# How to do a cascading update?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a group of tables with columns that have foreign key constraints on a user name column in another table. I've been instructed not to add `ON UPDATE CASCADE` to the table definition because we don't want to silently lose information from things like activity logs. We only want to explicitly cascade in this one instance. I haven't been able to find an example of how to do it in a query though. I'm thinking it would look something like

```
UPDATE CASCADE "MySchema"."MyTable"
SET user_name = "John Smith"
WHERE user_id = 1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You do it in your data definition, `CREATE TABLE`, of your referencing row not in an updating query, as very well demonstrated in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 45):

In Postgres (and other RDBMs) cascading updates apply exclusively to foreign keys. Example:

```
create table groups (
    group_id int primary key
);
    
create table users (
    user_id int primary key, 
    group_id int references groups on update cascade
);

insert into groups values (1);
insert into users values (1, 1);
update groups set group_id = 10 where group_id = 1;

select * from users;

 user_id | group_id 
---------+----------
       1 |       10
(1 row)
```

In fact, other options are not needed. If you feel the need to do this for a column which is not a foreign key, it means that the model is poorly designed (it is not [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)). On the other hand, the possibility of selective cascaded update of foreign keys does not solve any practical problem but rather breaks the general rules.

Comment: Does it contain false or misleading information? Deserves downvoting?

Comment: So I'd like the person who downvoted to show me the right direction.

Comment: If you want to reference different column, use
`group_id int references groups(different_column) on update cascade`

Comment: One other thing to note for @Tony's comment is that `different_column` must at least be `UNIQUE` in order to use it as a reference point of the constraint

Comment: The answer could be improved by either showing how to do what the question asks for or explaining why it's not possible and what other options there are.

Comment: I upvoted, but why is this feature available only for foreign keys? Wouldn't it make more sense to apply a setting once to a primary key column and be assured that updates would cascade to all the corresponding foreign keys? That's how I assumed it would work initially.

Comment: @HarshaLaxman - The rule in force gives more flexibility in designing relations. A table may contain many foreign keys, some of them should be updated automatically, others not. And conversely, a target table can be referenced by one table with cascaded updates and by another without them, depending on the designer's decision.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, you can't add a `CASCADE` option to an `UPDATE` like you can with a `DELETE`.

Instead, do the following in a (probably in a transaction).

## DROP original constraint / ADD temp constraint

Something like

```
ALTER fk_table DROP CONSTRAINT mytable__table_w_fk__fk;
ALTER fk_table ADD CONSTRAINT mytable__table_w_fk__fk
  FOREIGN KEY (fk) REFERENCES mytable (pk)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

## Do the update

```
UPDATE "MySchema"."MyTable"
SET user_name = "John Smith"
WHERE user_id = 1
```

## DROP temp constraint / ADD original constraint

```
ALTER fk_table DROP CONSTRAINT mytable__table_w_fk__fk;
ALTER fk_table ADD CONSTRAINT mytable__table_w_fk__fk
  FOREIGN KEY (fk) REFERENCES mytable (pk);
```