# Postgresql question for changing data without effecting table

Tags: sql, postgresql, row, multiple-columns

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhqAg.png)
The above image shows the table that I have created in postgresql.
Say if I  create an account saying 'entertainment' and add 40 entries to it over a month
before realizing that I spelt it as entertainmunt.
so now, you'd want to rename that account, right?
With this table structure..

how should achieve that?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103781/how-to-do-a-cascading-update) SO thread. It is almost identical to your question.

Comment: In your Account table, add an ID column with integer, or probably SERIAL, to have a better PK, than text based Account name, which as you suspect can change or get corrected over time.